# Fire jquery animate on same element while animation is in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 2 buttons with these code:

```
$('#btn1').on('click',function() {
   $('#div1').animate({left:500},1000);
});

$('#btn2').on('click',function() {
   $('#div1').animate({left:0},1000);
});
```

I want to be capable of firing the event of btn2 while btn1's event is still in progress. What is currently happening when I click both buttons fast is for example, I click btn1, the div goes and completes left:500 before actually firing btn2's event.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for `.stop()`? See: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 2):

You want to [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) all animations before firing the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the stop() function to accomplish this. Design both your event handlers like this:

```
$('#btn1').on('click',function() {
  $('#div1').stop().animate({left:500},1000);
});

$('#btn2').on('click',function() {
  $('#div1').stop()animate({left:0},1000);
});
```

This stops the div if currently animating and starts the new animation on it.